# R strings that include quotes ("")

Tags: r, string, replace

I am rephrasing my post to avoid confusion. I had two examples. the first one has a work around, but the second one does not. So I am removing the first example.

I am trying to replace portion of a string with another string. The string that needs to be replaced has embedded quotes.

```
mybigstring<-str_replace_all(mybigstring,c("text that has \"embedded\" quotes" = "something else"))
```

This replacement is not able to detect and replace the text that has double quotes in it! So using escape before quotes does not work. Is there a work around or solution for this?

Comment: Are you sure those backslashes are in the string, not just in what R prints?  Use `cat(mybigstring)` to see what's actually there, don't use `print()`.

Comment: The work around of using single quotes instead worked for that first example. But I just added the second example where I have to detect and replace the text that has double quotes in it - and that I am not able to do, and has no simple work around.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to use single quotation marks inside?

Because this should work (at least in this particular case):

```
mybigstring <- "</p><p>"
str_replace_all(mybigstring,c("</p><p>" = "<br style='mso-data-placement:same-cell;'/>"))
```

Comment: For this particular case, single quotes work!. Thank you. But it looks like I still have to find solution for this embedded single quotes, because now I have to replace the string that has embedded single quotes in it, and that does not seem to work either. I will clarify this by editing my post.

Comment: Well then you just need to escape them the way you did using `\"`. Like user2554330 said in the comment above, the standard print method in R prints the escape characters, but they are not really there in the underlying string. To see (just as user2554330 said): `cat(str_replace_all(mybigstring, c("</p><p>" = "<br style=\"mso-data-placement:same-cell;\"/>")))`

Comment: mybigstring<-str_replace_all(mybigstring,c("text that has \"embedded\" quotes" = "something else")). This is what I need to do, and escape does not work. It is not able to find the string that has quotes even if I add escape to the quotes.

Comment: So I edited t he post and removed the first example. When embedded quotes are in the text that I am replacing to - I made it work that was my first example. But when embedded quotes are in eth text that I am changing from - that does not work.